# Find the equation of the plane that passes through a point & is parallel/orthogonal to a plane/line

Tags: geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

Can someone please help me understand the difference between the following:

1. Find the equation of the plane that passes through the point $(2,-1,3)$ and is **parallel** to the **plane** $5x-2y+z-5=0$.

> *In this case, is the plane's normal vector equal to the other plane's $(5x-2y+z-5=0)$ normal vector? i.e. $n=(5,-2,1)$ Since they are
>   **parallel**? 
>  ∴ $(x-2,y+1,z-3).(5,-2,1)=0$, would then be the equation in vector form?*

2. Find the equation of the plane that passes through the point $(1,-1,2)$ and is **orthogonal/perpendicular** to the **plane** $x+2y-3z-4=0$

> *In this case, where the two planes are **orthogonal**, is the plane's normal vector **also** equal to the other plane's $(x+2y-3z-4=0)$
>   normal vector? i.e. $n=(1,2,-3)$ 
>  ∴ $(x-1,y+1,z-2).(1,2,-3)=0$,
>   would then be the equation in vector form?*

3. Find the equation of the plane that passes through the point $(1,-3,-4)$ and is **orthogonal/perpendicular** to the **line**: $x=4+2t, y=-2+3t, z=-5t$

> *In this case, where the plane is now **orthogonal** to a **line**, is the plane's normal vector equal to the line's $(x=4+2t, y=-2+3t,
> z=-5t)$ vector? i.e. $n=v=(2,3,-5)$ 
>  ∴
>   $(x-1,y+3,z+4).(2,3,-5)=0$, would then be the plane's equation in
>   vector form?*

Comment: There may be an error at #2 in the questions I have received in a study guide. I think another orthogonal plane should be given? Not just one. So that the cross product can be found.

Comment: While there is certainly an infinite number of planes that satisfy the description in #2, $(x-1,y+1,z-2)\cdot(1,2,-3)=0$ isn’t one of them.